# Exception from container-launch. Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn

when I tranfer the data from hdfs to hbase by using this commands :

```
hadoopusr@DESKTOP-1CFP2U7:~/hbase$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:title,cf:abstract,cf:first,cf:last,cf:Place covid_data /fthase/combined_covid.csv
```

it show my this error :

```
[2023-09-06 15:05:51.947]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

** following are the yarn-site.xm , bashrc file and mapred-site-xml**

[yarn-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ska.png)

[bashrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui1W0.png)

[mapred-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIPRZ.png)

please someone lookout this issue